# JIRA extract git commit using REST API

Tags: git, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I have DVCS plugin installed for JIRA, so jira will pull the commit information from github into the issues on the dashboard. However when I use jira rest api to query the issue, I could not get any information about the git commit. The commits and branches info showed up in the "Development" field, but when I use http://localhost:8000/rest/api/latest/issue/ADS-374to query. There is no "development" field. How do I get those informations? Thanks

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/332555/jira-extract-git-commit-using-rest-api
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/20644811/get-git-plug-in-information-from-jira-api

Comment: Is this information stored in a custom field? You might need to retrieve the list of fields to confirm the field id.

Comment: Did you solve this?